# How to format footnotes with Markdown on Tumblr?

Tags: tumblr, markdown

I'm not sure I can get proper documentation on this, I've been to this [tumblr help center](http://www.tumblr.com/help) and [this discussion on Meta SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/markdown-footnotes) about Markdown footnotes, I saw interesting comment from Arjan that Drupal made it possible.

How can I write [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) footnotes in Tumblr?

I tried `<sup>1</sup>`, which works on SE sites <sup>like so</sup>, but it doesn't work on [Tumblr](http://tumblr.com).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure you've got Tumblr set to format your posts with Markdown [here](http://www.tumblr.com/preferences). Then, the syntax is:

```
That's some text with a footnote.[^1]

[^1]: And that's the footnote.
```

As noted [here](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/extra/#footnotes).

Comment: Nice! It's working! Thanks for giving me the example snippet, Abby

Comment: No problem. Happy footnoting!